# How to use a regex from a variable in regex for integers

Tags: python, regex

I am using a **xml parser**(`from lxml import etree`) to get a regex written in java script. so I obtain them as a string.

Ex:

```
 7|14|103|14[598]|12[0-9]|
```

so how do I get a match for all the numbers like `7 14 103 145 149 120` .....

Comment: What do you mean under _how do I get a match_? A match on what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to read your mind here - you have a regex pattern as a string and you want to use it to find matches in another string? You can use your pattern directly:

```
import re

pattern = "7|14|103|14[598]|12[0-9]"  # your fetched regex pattern
target = "7 14 103 145 149 120..."  # a text to match against

print(re.findall(pattern, target))  # or re.match() if you just need a match or more info
# ['7', '14', '103', '14', '14', '120']
```

The problem, however, is with the pattern itself as it searches left to right so you won't be getting `14[598]` matched when there is `14` in the pattern preceding it - making that bit redundant. Then again, if you're fetching the regex pattern from an external source you don't get much in a way of controlling it.

Comment: is there a way to match the pattern using integers like the numbers 103,145 unlike string "103" ,"145". When I tried to match it with an integer it is asking for a  string input

Comment: @Shanmukh - You can turn your integer into a string and perform the match.